# duplicate rows in QStandardItemModel in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm trying to achieve something I though would be easy but cannot figure how to make it work.

In this basic example, I'm creating an address book, a single person can be in 2 groups, John Doe is a friend, but also a work colleague.

If I change his phoneNumber inside the friend group, it should also change in the work group.

This is how I first tried this with static content (in the end it is linked to a db)

```
 addressBookListModel = new QStandardItemModel(0, 4);
            addressBookListModel->setHeaderData(0,Qt::Horizontal,"First Name", Qt::DisplayRole);
            addressBookListModel->setHeaderData(0,Qt::Horizontal,"fn", Qt::UserRole);
            addressBookListModel->setHeaderData(1,Qt::Horizontal,"Last Name", Qt::DisplayRole);
            addressBookListModel->setHeaderData(1,Qt::Horizontal,"ln", Qt::UserRole);
            addressBookListModel->setHeaderData(2,Qt::Horizontal,"E-Mail", Qt::DisplayRole);
            addressBookListModel->setHeaderData(2,Qt::Horizontal,"mail", Qt::UserRole);
            addressBookListModel->setHeaderData(3,Qt::Horizontal,"Phone Number", Qt::DisplayRole);
            addressBookListModel->setHeaderData(3,Qt::Horizontal,"phone", Qt::UserRole);
```

Then inserting the data :

```
//Group 1
            QStandardItem * work = new QStandardItem("Work");

            QList<QStandardItem*> workgroup;
            workgroup << work ;
            addressBookListModel->appendRow(workgroup);

//group 2
            QStandardItem * friends = new QStandardItem("Friends");

            QList<QStandardItem*> friendgroup;
            friendgroup << friends ;
            addressBookListModel->appendRow(friendgroup);

//One contact in both groups
            QStandardItem * fn = new QStandardItem("John");
            QStandardItem * ln = new QStandardItem("Doe");
            QStandardItem * mail = new QStandardItem("john.doe@gmail.com");
            QStandardItem * phone = new QStandardItem("+123456789");

            QList<QStandardItem*> rowitems;
            rowitems << fn << ln << mail << phone;
            work->appendRow(rowitems);
            friends->appendRow(row items);
```

but this only inserts john doe inside work like this :

[image]

I Thought this would be because row items is not a pointer, so I tried it this way :

```
//One contact in both groups 2

            QStandardItem * fn = new QStandardItem("John");
            QStandardItem * ln = new QStandardItem("Doe");
            QStandardItem * mail = new QStandardItem("john.doe@gmail.com");
            QStandardItem * phone = new QStandardItem("+123456789");

            QList<QStandardItem*> rowitems;
            rowitems << fn << ln << mail << phone;

            QList<QStandardItem*> rowitemsB;
            rowitemsB << fn << ln << mail << phone;


            work->appendRow(rowitems);
            friends->appendRow(rowitemsB);
```

But this gave me the exact same result, John Doe is not present inside Friends, although in both cases, there is an arrow indicating the presence of a child.

Any Idea how to make the same data appear twice?

Comment: What happens if you insert second item with different first name?

Comment: @jpo38 nice idea, i tried, putting jane, Jane appears but other columns are empty, as if a qstandarditem could only appear once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `QStandardItem` can be added once and only once to a `QStandardItemModel`. Check your debugger log, I'm sure QT writes debug messages saying it's not allowed when you insert the same item twice. By the way, what would return `QStandrardItem::index()` of an item inserted twice (this method returns row/column position of the item in the `QStandardItemModel`)?

So you have to create different `QStandardItem`. You should do like that:

```
void addEntry( const QString& first, const QString& last, const QString& mail, const QString& tel, QStandardItem* parent )
{
    QStandardItem * fn = new QStandardItem(first);
    QStandardItem * ln = new QStandardItem(last);
    QStandardItem * mail = new QStandardItem(mail);
    QStandardItem * phone = new QStandardItem(tel);
    QList<QStandardItem*> rowitems;
    rowitems << fn << ln << mail << phone;
    parent->appendRow(rowitems);
}

...
addEntry( "John", "Doe", "john.doe@gmail.com", "+123456789", work );
addEntry( "John", "Doe", "john.doe@gmail.com", "+123456789", friends );
```

Comment: but then they are different. editing an item will not change the other one

Comment: True, you'll have to handle that yourself using `itemChanged(QStandardItem * item)`. You could also specialize your own `QStandardItem` managing links with other items and updating them on change so that changing one would change the other ones.

Comment: I do get the idea, was just thinking about subclassing qstandarditem to make the values of 2 different items use the same pointer. so they both have their own position and attributes / flags, but share the value

Comment: You can have a "master" `QStandarItem` and a "slave". "slave" would have a pointer to the "master" and return "master" values be overriding `QStandardItem::data` (returning `master->data(...)`)